# Will unlinked pages on a WordPress site get indexed by Google?

Tags: google, wordpress, links

When you add a page to WordPress but you don't create a menu item for it and you don't have any link on your website to the page, will the page still be indexed by Google?

Comment: Do you want the page indexed or not?     If you don't want it indexed, you need to protected it because Google may just find it anyway.   If you do want it indexed, you should link to it or Google won't rank it very well.   It doesn't have to be from a menu, a link on anywhere on any page or in any post will do just fine.

Answer (score 4):

*Google and Bing bots are not mind readers*

If you have a link on your site, another site, or within a sitemap, then only then will it become indexable. It can't index something it can't find.

If you do not want Google indexing the page, then you should use [no-index](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710?hl=en), [robots.txt](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=en), or both.